# what is "period" column represent in AWS cloudwatch metric graph?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lambda

I created the number metric graph for lambda function like latency, the total number of invocation etc. I also created a custom metric filter which will give me errors and warnings count in logs for time range we specify.

Everything is working and result for the custom metric are correct. I don't understand the use of "period" column chart in the dashboard shown in the this [cloudwatch single widget image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaClT.png). Can you explain the use of "period" and why it is there when we already have time-range like 1 H,3H, 1W

Comment: Hi, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying *Thanks* for the time someone took to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Period in metrics displayed as **Number** simply describe how far in the past you are collecting the stats. For other display modes, e.g. **Line** or **Stack** the period is the time between each displayed data point. So on one graph you can have *3 hours of data* with **5 min period** which will give you 36 points on the graph. In *Number* display you'll simply see the last data point with stats collected over the last *Period*.

In your screenshot - on the first line you are calculating a **Sum** of all your Lambda errors over the last **30 days**. If you change the **Period** to e.g. *7 days* the number on the dashboard will show the *Sum* of the Lambda errors over the last *7 days*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still I’ve one doubt. So if I make graph with 5min and 7 days period for time range of 7 days(sum of lambda errors). will it show me the same result?